# How to improve slow TSQL query involving count distinct?

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd appreciate if someone could explain a huge performance difference I encountered with and without `count distinct` in TSQL. I have a table with the following columns:

- country_code (varchar(100), null)
- item_code (varcher(50), null)
- item_price (int, null)
- item_quantity (tinyint, null)
- user_no (int, null)

What I want is a sum of item_price, item_quantity, distinct count of users on the item_code level, by country. Hence the following query:

```
SELECT country_code
      ,item_code
      ,TotalSales = SUM (item_price)
      ,TotalPurchase = SUM (item_quantity)
      ,UniqueBuyer = COUNT (DISTINCT user_no)
FROM TABLE_SALES WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY item_code, country_code
ORDER BY country_code, item_code
```

The query was excruciatingly slow and didn't finish in 1.5 hours. However when I broke down the query and ran the `sum` and `count distinct` parts separately, each took less than a minute.

So I wonder why `count distinct` adds such a huge burden in combination while isn't a big deal on its own? And given the case, is there any better way to handle the query altogether?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is there an index on `user_no` ?

Comment: @marc_s unfortunately there's no index on any of these columns:(

Comment: That's an issue for sure. How many records does the table has?

Comment: @Rahul the whole table is huge and has about 1.5 million rows. I know the index will speed things up, but unfortunately I don't have access to add it.

Comment: Then ask someone who have access to that table. Also, try adding a `WHERE` condition (OR) `HAVING` condition to your query to work on limited set of rows.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the advice. However, I'm still wondering why the `count distinct` ran so much faster on its own even without an index?

Comment: My guess is that the Query Optimizer chose the wrong index, and most of your time was spent on Bookmark Lookup. It's hard to tell without an execution plan. You can force a clustered index scan by specifying a hint: `WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(0))` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ZoffDino Thanks for the advice. I tested it but it didn't make a significant difference (30 mins and still running).

Comment: Can you post your execution plan for both approaches here?

Comment: @ZoffDino Wish I could, but I don't have the permission... It says "SHOWPLAN permission denied in database"